# How to install free ssl in cpanel

Tags: wordpress, ssl, cpanel

I want to create ssl for my site but i don't have enough budgets so can you suggest me to install in **cpanel** of **wordpress**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use wp-letsencrypt-ssl plugin in wordpress then it will ask for domain verification, After that you will be able to generate pem key, bundle, cert , which you need to install in your cpnale are names as ssl/tls

Answer (score 0):

You can use the free version of [SSL Zen](https://wordpress.org/plugins/ssl-zen/)
It works with cPanel, they generate an SSL certificate and help you install it.